# Initialize struct directly for my unit testing in Go

Tags: go

```
var tests = []struct {
    input    []int
    expected int
}{
    {{2, 2}, 4},
}
```

This throws **missing type in composite literal**. Is there anyway I can do this directly instead of defining a struct type and then create a variable of the type and then initialize it. The above is for simple unit test for a sum of 2 integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the type for the int slice:

```
var tests = []struct {
    input    []int
    expected int
}{
  {[]int{2, 2}, 4},
}
```